# SQL iterate for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this table:

```
|ID| GruopID | Status | Date        |
| 2| 1       | S1     | 7/29/2011   |
| 3| 1       | S2     | 7/30/2011   |
| 9| 1       | S1     | 8/02/2011   |
| 7| 1       | S1     | 8/03/2011   |
| 8| 1       | S1     | 8/04/2011   |
| 1| 2       | S1     | 7/28/2011   |
| 4| 2       | S2     | 7/30/2011   |
| 5| 2       | S3     | 8/01/2011   |
| 6| 3       | S1     | 8/02/2011   |
```

and also a specific date from an outside source: 7/31/2011

I need a query which will give me **for each groupID** the **closest upper and lower** date, so the result will be:

```
|ID| GruopID | Status | Date        |
| 3| 1       | S2     | 7/30/2011   |
| 9| 1       | S1     | 8/02/2011   |
| 4| 2       | S2     | 7/30/2011   |
| 5| 2       | S3     | 8/01/2011   |
| 6| 3       | S1     | 8/02/2011   |
```

Can someone please help me and show me the query?

Comment: I am using sql server. And comparibg to the outside source date: 7/31/2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforward approach:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.GroupID, t1.Status, t1.Date
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE t1.Date IN (
    SELECT MAX(t2.Date)
    FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE t2.GroupID = t1.GroupID
    AND t2.Date <= '7/31/2011'
    UNION
    SELECT MIN(t3.Date)
    FROM MyTable t3
    WHERE t3.GroupID = t1.GroupID
    AND t3.Date >= '7/31/2011'
)
```

Please note that the number of rows per group may not always be two.

- If there is a record with precisely that date 7/31/2011, then a single record will be returned for that group.
- If all records of a group are either before or after 7/31/2011, then a single record will be returned for that group.
- If the table contains duplicate combinations of GroupID and Date, then more than two rows may be returned. This is inherent to the fact that no 'correct' way to choose between the duplicates has been defined.

Comment: This method may give incorrect result, if dates are not unique per group.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Thanks, I added this and some more considerations to my answer. Since OP never mentioned how to handle duplicates, there is no way to judge whether current behavior is 'incorrect'.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I shouldn't have said "incorrect". I meant more than one row per `GroupID` and `Date` if there are duplicates.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov No offense taken man; I really appreciate the comment, as it might well be a realistic scenario that OP should take into account.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic `greatest-n-per-group` query. I would use `CROSS APPLY` here.

Make sure that you have index on `(GroupID, dt, ID)`.

Most likely you have a table `Groups` that has a list of all `GroupIDs`. In the query below I use CTE to get a list of all distinct `GroupIDs`.

**Sample data**

I added few rows to show how the query works in various cases.

```
DECLARE @VarDate date = '2011-07-31';
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, GroupID int, Status varchar(2), dt date);
INSERT INTO @T (ID, GroupID, Status, dt) VALUES
(2, 1, 'S1', '2011-07-29'),
(3, 1, 'S2', '2011-07-30'),
(9, 1, 'S1', '2011-08-02'),
(7, 1, 'S1', '2011-08-03'),
(8, 1, 'S1', '2011-08-04'),
(1, 2, 'S1', '2011-07-28'),
(4, 2, 'S2', '2011-07-30'),
(5, 2, 'S3', '2011-08-01'),
(6, 3, 'S1', '2011-08-02'),

(11, 4, 'S1', '2011-08-04'),
(12, 4, 'S2', '2011-08-02'),
(13, 4, 'S3', '2011-08-02'),
(21, 4, 'S1', '2011-07-04'),
(22, 4, 'S2', '2011-07-04'),
(23, 4, 'S3', '2011-07-04'),

(31, 5, 'S1', '2011-07-31'),
(32, 5, 'S2', '2011-07-31'),
(33, 5, 'S3', '2011-07-31'),
(34, 5, 'S1', '2011-07-31'),
(35, 5, 'S2', '2011-07-31'),
(36, 5, 'S3', '2011-07-31'),

(41, 6, 'S1', '2011-07-31');
```

**Query**

For each `GroupID` we find the upper and lower row using `CROSS APPLY`, then `UNION ALL` upper and lower results together.

```
WITH
CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT GroupID
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    CA.ID
    ,Groups.GroupID
    ,CA.Status
    ,CA.dt
FROM
    CTE_Groups AS Groups
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            T.ID
            ,T.Status
            ,T.dt
        FROM @T AS T
        WHERE
            T.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
            AND T.dt >= @VarDate
        ORDER BY T.dt, ID
    ) AS CA

UNION ALL

SELECT
    CA.ID
    ,Groups.GroupID
    ,CA.Status
    ,CA.dt
FROM
    CTE_Groups AS Groups
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            T.ID
            ,T.Status
            ,T.dt
        FROM @T AS T
        WHERE
            T.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
            AND T.dt <= @VarDate
        ORDER BY T.dt DESC, ID DESC
    ) AS CA

ORDER BY GroupID, dt;
```

**Result**

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| ID | GroupID | Status |     dt     |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  3 |       1 | S2     | 2011-07-30 |
|  9 |       1 | S1     | 2011-08-02 |
|  4 |       2 | S2     | 2011-07-30 |
|  5 |       2 | S3     | 2011-08-01 |
|  6 |       3 | S1     | 2011-08-02 |
| 23 |       4 | S3     | 2011-07-04 |
| 12 |       4 | S2     | 2011-08-02 |
| 31 |       5 | S1     | 2011-07-31 |
| 36 |       5 | S3     | 2011-07-31 |
| 41 |       6 | S1     | 2011-07-31 |
| 41 |       6 | S1     | 2011-07-31 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
```